# Bootstrap Datepicker convert format from dd.mm.yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd before inserting to MySQL

Tags: jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

Is there a fairly simple way to convert the format of Bootstrap Datepicker before inserting the data to database?

My page had the HTML5 date input until I realized it was only working in Chrome.

The thing is I need to display the data on the webpage in a norwegian/european format: dd.mm.yyyy and then insert the value as a "default" date (yyyy-mm-dd) to MySQL. Column in database is Date type.

I'm not good at javascript, so I'm hoping there's a simple addon to the script that fixes this.

```
<!-- Datepicker JS -->
<script src="datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="datepicker/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.no.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
  $('#date').datepicker({
  locale: 'no'
  });
});
</script>

<div class="col-md-2 form-group">
        <label for="date">Date</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="date" id="date" data-provide="datepicker">
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

mysql database needs date format in Y-m-d format so in case to insert this date format in the database you will need to change the date format that comes from datepicker.

user this code to convert

```
date('Y-m-D',strtotime('YOUR DATEPICKER DATE'));
```

Comment: Nice one! Did it like this: $mydate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['mydate'])); That puts the date into the db in the right format. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Use this Pal, this will work I think:

```
$('#date').datepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
});
```

or this will also work:

```
$('#date').datepicker({
dateFormat: 'DD, MM, d, yy'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

User following code to get yyyy-mm-dd format.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  $('#date').datepicker({
  locale: 'no',
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In *jquery* we can convert date to any format & then send via *ajax* to server side with this custom format, this way:

```
$("#date").data('datepicker').getFormattedDate('yyyy-mm-dd');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this dirst you have to add this plugin in your script files then you try this code same as like which i gave. and you can change the format.

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Date").datepicker({
        //maxDate: "+0D",
        //changeMonth: true,
        //changeYear: true,
        //yearRange: "-100:+0",
        //minDate: '-0d',
        dateFormat: "M/dd/yy",
        });
     });

   </script>
```